# authserver.mojang.com error (all mojang servers working)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking, minecraft-launcher

I always login and it says in parenthesis, `(Error 505: authserver.mojang.com)` I need help fixing this error. I've tried reinstalling it and keeping all of the servers, AND this launcher says it doesn't need java.
I tried restarting the computer too. Tell me steps to fix this error please.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a networking issue with your home network. Verify that your name servers are correct, and that your IP matches the subnet of the gateway for your router.

If your IP address of your computer is 192.168.1.100, for example, your gateway is likely 192.168.1.1. Sometimes this can happen if your DNS hosts aren't correct as well. I had this happen when I changed the subnet of my home router from a 10.0.0 subnet to 192.168.1. Once I fixed the addresses, it worked fine.